# Totally ramified extensions

Tags: ring-theory, galois-theory

Let $k$ be a separably closed field of positive characteristic $p$ and let $K$ be its algebraic closure.

How can we reduce questions about equations over $k$ to equations over $K$? How do $k$-algebras relate to $K$ algebras?

Comment: @ThomasPreu I'm not sure how your example is related to the question. $\mathbb{Q}$ is not at all separably closed, and $\mathbb{C}$ is not its algebraic closure. I think an important point of the question (which btw is way too short and vague and should have much more details and motivation) is that a lot of nice results about algebraically closed fields actually hold over separably closed fields, so the situation of $k$ is already pretty good. The question is: in characterietic $p$, what is gained from separably closed to algebraically closed?

Comment: @CaptainLama So you do not mean "totally ramified" but "purely inseparable". This makes more sense. Then my previous comment will not help at all.